# SSIS DB Catalog Table giving System out of Memory Exception

Tags: sql, ssis

when working with SSIDB Catalog system tables,i am facing an issue of System.out of memory exception when querying the table.
                 *Select * from Internal.operation_message*
I have a system memory of 1.5 TB on the server and this is the first time i am facing issue on the server.Any suggestions please

Comment: That's not the SSISDB or SQL Server itself throwing that error message but the SSMS client itself. If you close and reopen SSMS, you'll notice that the query now works (although you'll likely want a filter as I have 7M rows in that table after only executing 190 packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but although i am reopening it ,the table is so huge that its not showing me whole data and gives out of memory exception.I have been creating some indexes on the Internal.operation_messages and internal.event_messages table but no luck.Also when i try opening view all execution in SSIDB Catalog it gives the same error..Please help

Comment: Just because you live at a gas station doesn't mean you can drive further than the tank on your automobile. Same thing here-your server has plenty of memory but the SSMS application cannot use all of the server memory. By select all the rows and all of the columns from that table, SSMS runs out of memory attempting to display said data. PUT A FILTER ON YOUR QUERY TO STOP RUNNING OUT OF MEMORY IN YOUR CLIENT

Comment: Thats Absolutely correct,but this is not only happening when i am doing select * on the table but also when i am trying to view execution report in SSIDB Catalog